# Javascript performance: console.time

Tags: javascript, performance

I'm having some trouble understanding why the timing would be different for the following two implementations of `console.time`. I'm trying to test a function I wrote, but when I implement the `console.time` in the following two ways, I get very different answers...

To try to diagnose this, I used `Array.prototype.sort()` and the same timing inconsistencies were produced. `arr` is an array of length n with random integers. I tested it with arrays of random integers of length 10, 100, 1000, 10000, 100000.

**Note:** I know the [performance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance) api exists, but I want to understand what's happening with `console.time`.

Method 1

```
function timeLog(title, arr) {
    console.time(title);
    arr.sort();
    console.timeEnd(title);
}

timeLog('time test 1', arr);
```

Method 2:

```
console.time('time test 2');
arr.sort();
console.timeEnd('time test 2');
```

My results:

```
with method 1
10 item array: 0.198ms
100 item array: 0.196ms
1000 item array: 3.386ms
10000 item array: 65.558ms
100000 item array: 326.774ms

with method 2
10 item array: 0.022ms
100 item array: 0.081ms
1000 item array: 0.534ms
10000 item array: 12.865ms
100000 item array: 77.395ms
```

Runnable Snippet:

```js
function randomArray(n) {
  return Array.apply(null, Array(n))
    .map(function() {
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000);
    });
}

function timeLog(title, array) {
  console.time(title);
  array.sort();
  console.timeEnd(title);
}

var arr10 = randomArray(10);
var arr100 = randomArray(100);
var arr1000 = randomArray(1000);
var arr10000 = randomArray(10000);
var arr100000 = randomArray(100000);

var arr10_2 = arr10.slice();
var arr100_2 = arr100.slice();
var arr1000_2 = arr1000.slice();
var arr10000_2 = arr10000.slice();
var arr100000_2 = arr100000.slice();

console.log('method 1: with timeLog function')
timeLog('10 item array', arr10)
timeLog('100 item array', arr100)
timeLog('1000 item array', arr1000)
timeLog('10000 item array', arr10000)
timeLog('100000 item array', arr100000)
console.log();

console.log('method 2: just console.time');
console.time('10 item array-2')
arr10_2.sort()
console.timeEnd('10 item array-2')
console.time('100 item array-2')
arr100_2.sort()
console.timeEnd('100 item array-2')
console.time('1000 item array-2')
arr1000_2.sort()
console.timeEnd('1000 item array-2')
console.time('10000 item array-2')
arr10000_2.sort()
console.timeEnd('10000 item array-2')
console.time('100000 item array-2')
arr100000_2.sort()
console.timeEnd('100000 item array-2')
```

Comment: Um....you're calling `timeLog` with three arguments, but it has only two formal parameters, and the second one is `arr` but you're passing in `myFunction`...? I'm guessing test error. Separately: Are you testing these on the same starting data? Hopefully you're not testing the second one on the array the first one sorted...

Comment: Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: Good catch! Yes, I made sure they weren't operating on the same array before running these tests. However, they aren't operating on the arrays with the same elements, so I'll have to change that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just that you're testing them both at the same time, and optimization is kicking in during the first pass. (And/or other testing methodology issues such as re-sorting the same array, etc.; can't tell from what's in the question.)

If I do that on a 10,000-item array, being careful to use the *same* values for each test (and being careful that the second one doesn't sort the array sorted by the first one), on Chrome I reliably see faster times for the second `sort` than the first&nbsp— regardless of whether I use `timeLog` first, or the inline code first:

Using `timeLog` first:

```js
var arr1 = Array.from({length:10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
var arr2 = arr1.slice();

function timeLog(title, arr) {
    console.time(title);
    arr.sort();
    console.timeEnd(title);
}

timeLog('time test 1', arr1);

console.time('time test 2');
arr2.sort();
console.timeEnd('time test 2');
```

Using inline code first:

```js
var arr1 = Array.from({length:10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
var arr2 = arr1.slice();

function timeLog(title, arr) {
    console.time(title);
    arr.sort();
    console.timeEnd(title);
}

console.time('time test 2');
arr2.sort();
console.timeEnd('time test 2');

timeLog('time test 1', arr1);
```

Whereas if I do it **twice**, I see that the difference disappears the second time:

**Twice**, using `timeLog` first:

```js
var arr1 = Array.from({length:10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
var arr2 = arr1.slice();

var arr3 = arr1.slice();
var arr4 = arr1.slice();

function timeLog(title, arr) {
    console.time(title);
    arr.sort();
    console.timeEnd(title);
}

timeLog('timeLog 1', arr1);

console.time('inline 1');
arr2.sort();
console.timeEnd('inline 1');

timeLog('timeLog 2', arr1);

console.time('inline 2');
arr2.sort();
console.timeEnd('inline 2');
```

**Twice**, using inline code first:

```js
var arr1 = Array.from({length:10000}, () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000));
var arr2 = arr1.slice();

var arr3 = arr1.slice();
var arr4 = arr1.slice();

function timeLog(title, arr) {
    console.time(title);
    arr.sort();
    console.timeEnd(title);
}

console.time('inline 1');
arr2.sort();
console.timeEnd('inline 1');

timeLog('timeLog 1', arr1);

console.time('inline 2');
arr2.sort();
console.timeEnd('inline 2');

timeLog('timeLog 2', arr1);
```

Comment: Interesting. Yes I wasn't using the same values each time so I'll have to try that. So interesting that it doesn't matter the order! Thanks for the help!

Comment: @SneakyToes: Well, the order thing makes sense. V8 starts out running code interpreted (it used to use a fast compiler, but now it starts with an interpreter) and then compiles the code on-the-fly if it looks like a hotspot. `Array#sort` is implemented in JavaScript ([code is here](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/master/src/js/array.js#L994)), so you sort a 10,000-entry array and it's going to say that the compare function is a hotspot and compile... :-)